# MySQL "limit" returns the wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I perform two queries in Mysql with "limit":

query one:

```
SELECT * FROM staff s, department d WHERE s.departId = d.id AND s.statusid = 1  LIMIT 10;
```

result one:
[image]

query two:

```
SELECT * FROM staff s, department d WHERE s.departId = d.id AND s.statusid = 1  LIMIT 1;
```

result two:
[image]

Question:

I wonder why the second query doesn't return record of id=100000 instead of id=100001;
Thanks for replying in advance.

Comment: there is absolutely no code to support this question. All there is here, is a screenshot.

Comment: and your acceptance record isn't great neither

Comment: add `order by S.ID asc` and it will

Comment: Screenshot is better than code in this situation, that clearly explain my question.

Comment: NO, screen shot is never better. In future do post it as text rather.

Comment: already changed my question description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that's cause you haven't specified any `order by` clause and hence the order of data returned is not guaranteed. If you need a specific order for the resultant data then do specify that using `order by` clause like

```
order by s.departId desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Neither of your queries specifies an ordering, which means the database is free to order your data however it wants to complete the query. If you want to sort by the `id` column add `ORDER BY s.id ASC` to your queries:

```sql
SELECT * FROM staff s, department d WHERE ... ORDER BY s.id ASC LIMIT 10;

SELECT * FROM staff s, department d WHERE ... ORDER BY s.id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `order by id`  clause if you want to return data based on id in ascending order use `order by id desc` if in descending